# Reassign or replace a variable's type in C#

Tags: c#, variables, types, replace, action

This is something I would need to do to create a flexible logic structure that I need for a class.

The class is like this:

```
public class myclass {
  public Action myaction;
  public int actionparams;
  public string label;

  public void myactionfunction() {
    //do void parameter action
  }

  public void myactionfunction(int myparam) {
    //do one parameter action
  }

  public void myactionfunction(int myparam, int myparam2) {
    //do two parameter action
  }
}
```

Well the problem I'm facing is that I will use this class where 'myaction' can arbitrarily require none or as much as six parameters. Since 'Action' needs to be defined for each parameter it's meant to support, I could certainly define as much 'myactions' that I expect parameters for, but that would not be ideal, since I'd need to hardwire parameter types there.

I am hoping that there's a way in which I could 'simply' reassign myaction's type, so that in some manner I can do something like

```
myaction.type = Action<string,int,int>; //i know this looks bad, but should give the idea
```

I have read about delegate declarations, but can't figure if there's a way to use them for my purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: Will an instance of the class (object) always be bound to an action with the same parameters?

Comment: Different instances of the class will have a different number of action parameters as a matter of fact

Comment: That is not what I was asking...

Comment: Thanks for your help but I can't figure out what you're asking for then.

Comment: My question was: does a single object always contain an action with the same parameters? If so, you could pass the types of the parameters to the constructor of the object or as generics and use this information with the class to allow some checking. I'll add an example below.

Comment: Oh yes thanks for clarifying. Parameters don't change once they've been assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You can, however, use a capture such that everything is `Action`, i.e.:

```
public void myactionfunction() {
    myaction = () => DoSomethingWithoutParameters();
}

public void myactionfunction(int myparam) {
    myaction = () => DoSomethingWithOneParameter(myparam);
}

public void myactionfunction(int myparam, int myparam2) {
    myaction = () => DoSomethingWithTwoParameters(myparam, myparam2);
}
```

if these actually represent default values, then use default values!

```
public void SomeMethod(int x = 123, int y = 456) {
    myaction = () => Foo(x, y);
}
```

which can be called via any of:

```
SomeMethod();
SomeMethod(1);
SomeMethod(1, 2);
SomeMethod(x: 1);
SomeMethod(y: 2);
SomeMethod(x: 1, y: 2);
SomeMethod(y: 2, x: 1);
```

Comment: This looks good. Never saw the notation here though. "myaction = ()" is defined a 'capture'?

Comment: @roamcel no, that (along with the `=>`) is the start of a *lambda*; the capture is simply: that the lambda involves a local variable or parameter (`myparam` is "captured", for example). BTW, it is semantically identical (in this case) to: `myAction = delegate { DoSomethingWithOneParameter(myparam); };`

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. I'm accepting this as the correct answer since you actually clarified that a variable type can't be reassigned, and offered an informative workaround.

Comment: still bad practice, as I see it. you need to create `myactionfunction` for each number of possible parameters. and for each type of parameters...

Comment: @Roee the main question of the types *seems* to revolve around the delegate field's type. If the method handles a known set of combinations of parameters, then overloads are not unreasonable; as I mention, optional parameters might help with this (reducing the overloads to one single method). Beyond that, we'd need to know a lot more about the expected signatures to propose viable options.

Comment: I suspect the design of the original question... chances are that the entire construction is not needed.

Comment: @Roee I could counter that `params object[]` is bad practice; that tells the caller **nothing** about the valid calling signatures; frankly, it's a cheat.

Comment: @MarcGravell, that's true but also having multiple function overloading when the only different between each overload is the number of integer parameters it gets.

Comment: @Roee that depends on the scenario; is it **any** number of integers? who knows. The `params` approach might be valid if they all represent the same thing (for example, values to a `Sum`/`Avg`, or opaque values to a `string.Format`) - however, if each position has **distinct and specified purpose**, then IMO the `params` approach is incorrect. But... whatever.

Comment: @MarcGravell, lets agree that it's good to know both ways and choose the one that fit your situation. Peace.

Answer (score 2):

you can just do:

```
public void myactionfunction(params object[] prms)
{
    int[] intArray = (int[])prms;
    //do what ever you need to do...
}
```

this also allow you to pass different params type for each action:

```
public void myactionfunction(params object[] prms)
{
    if (myAction == ???)
    {
        string param1 = (string)prms[0];
        //use string as first param
    }
    else
    {
        int param1 = (int)prms[0];
        //use int as first param.
    }
    //do what ever you need to do...
}
```

This can be called like this:

```
myactionfunction();
myactionfunction(1);
//and also
myactionfunction(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Comment: Better use 'params int[] prms' when only using `int` params.

Comment: Very nice idea, using object and doing proper casting afterwards. This has put me on the right track to solve my problem ideally. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, that depend on what he needs. As I write in the second paragraph it can be used for different params type this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an [optional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) parameters

```
public void myactionfunction(int myparam, int myparam2 = 0, int myparam3 = 0) {
...
}


void Test()
{
    myactionfunction(5); // Will call myactionfunction(5, 0, 0)
    myactionfunction(5, 10) // Will call myactionfunction(5, 10, 0)
    myactionfunction(1, myparam3: 7) // Will call myactionfunction(1, 0, 7)
}
```

Comment: That will only work when the type of the parameters is known, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: This was a very useful example, despite not being ideal for my need. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

With regard to changing the action, you can use Generics, however unfortunately you can't define `Action` as a constraint... so its a bit open.

```
public class MyClass<TAction> 
{
    public TAction Action{get;set;}   
}
```

Usage could then be (for Action with 1 string & 2 int param):

```
var c = new MyClass<Action<string,int,int>>();
```

And you can then assign an `Action` with

```
c.Action = (s,i1,i2) => Console.WriteLine("Params were: {0}, {1},{2}",s,i1,i2);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/DUI63303